# Javascript: reusing function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need some help with this. I have wrote some code that with the press a button-- a specific set of letters are put in an interval. The code is working seamlessly for one set of letters (the vowels) but when I try to reuse the function for all the letters in the alphabet it seems to be taking from the first set of letters. How will I be able reuse the function? Thank you in advance.

```js
var allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
var vowels = 'aeiouy'.split('');
var _timer;
var levelButton2 = document.querySelector("#levelButton2");
var stopButton = document.querySelector("#stopButton");
var startButton = document.querySelector("#startButton");

// Controls vowels
levelButton2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    getRandom(vowels);
 });
 
 // stop button
 stopButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    clearTimeout(_timer);
 });
 
 // Function that is being reused
 
 function getRandom (letters) {
     var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
     console.log('set random' , randomSet)
     document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
     _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(vowels), 1000);
 };


 //controls all letters
startButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    getRandom(allLetters);
 });
 
 // stop button
 stopButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    clearTimeout(_timer);
 });
 
 // Function that is being reused
 
 function getRandom (letters) {
     var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
     console.log('set random' , randomSet)
     document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
     _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(allLetters), 1000);
 };
```

Comment: *Totally* a side comment ... `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")` vs. `'aeiouy'.split('')` — you should be consistent in your use of quotes; either stick with single or stick with double (I use single because it's more common to want double-quotes in a quoted string)

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `getRandom` twice. And the second instance, it invokes itself in the timer using `allLetters` instead of the `letters` argument being passed in. The solution is to simply remove the redundant declaration and ensure you are passing the correct argument when calling itself iteratively:

```
function getRandom (letters) {
     var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
     console.log('set random' , randomSet)
     document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;

     // Use `letters` when invoking `getRandom()` again, not `vowels` or `allLetters`
     _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(letters), 1000);
 };
```

Comment: Thank you so much Terry. This worked for me. But if I wanted to reuse this about 4 times, will I continue to use the format above? Thank you.

Comment: @mediamike182 Yes that should work. You only need to declare the function once. And you can reuse it as many times as you want as long as you pass the correct array in the first argument.

Comment: Yes, everything works now. Thank you so much for your help Terry!